# Characterize the set of $(x_1,x_2)$ that make a quadratic form positive

Tags: quadratic-forms

Given a real-valued matrix
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a<0 <b$ and $a c < b^2$, how can I characterize the values $x = (x_1,x_2)$ that satisfy
$x^\top M x > 0$?

The eigenvalues of $M$ are
$$
\lambda_\pm = \frac{a+c}2 \pm \sqrt{\Big(\frac{a-c}{2}\Big)^2+b^2}.
$$
The condition $ac<b^2$ implies $\lambda_- < 0 < \lambda_+,$ hence $M$ is not positive definite or negative definite.

Comment: For the matrix $M$ to be p.d. or equivalently the corresponding quadratic form to be p.d., $\det (M)>0$ and $a>0$ must hold. This is an iff condition. See [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Answer (score 1):

$M$ is simetric and so there exist $U$ such that $M=U^{t}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_{+} & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_{-} \end{pmatrix}U,\ UU^{t}=U^{t}U=I$. Since $x^{t}Mx=(Ux)^{t}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_{+} & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_{-} \end{pmatrix}(Ux)$ and $\lambda_- < 0 < \lambda_+,$, the $(x_{1},x_{2})$ shearched are precisly those such that $Ux=(\mu_1,\mu_2)^{t}$ satisfies $\lambda_{}\mu_{1}^{2}+\lambda_{-}\mu_{2}^{2}>0$. I left the details to you.

Comment: Thank you, but does that not lead me back to the original problem?
When I plug $x = U^\top (\mu_1, \mu_2)^\top$ into $\lambda_+ \mu_1^2 + \lambda_- \mu_2^2 > 0,$ I get another quadratic form for $(x_1, x_2).$

Comment: The same quadratic form, in fact.